# Em HTML5 os elementos nulos devem ser fechados com ">" ou com "/>"?

Tags: html5, html-tags, sintaxe

Em HTML 5, existe uma série de elementos nulos, que de acordo com a [especificação](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#void-elements) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> e [exemplos dados](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#image-maps) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> pela W3C, os mesmos são fechados utilizando apenas `>`:

**Elementos Nulos**

```css
area, base, br, col, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, menuitem, meta,
param, source, track, wbr
```

De acordo com muitos artigos na internet, como [este na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> ou [este na C#corner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/667ddf/img-tag-in-html5/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>, os mesmos indicam (ou ilustram) que os elementos devem ser fechados com `/>`.

## Pergunta

Em HTML5, tipo de documento `<!DOCTYPE html>`, os elementos devem ser fechados de que maneira?

```html
<meta charset=utf-8>
```

ou

```html
<meta charset=utf-8 />
```

Comment: Relacionado (em Inglês): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5

Comment: @Sergio Já havia lido, mas essa pergunta e respetivas respostas está uma grande confusão... inicialmente a pergunta tinha um erro no código ao invés de `/>` estava `\>`, razão pela qual o validador da W3C indicar que existiam erros... depois a pergunta foi editada e gerou-se uma enorme confusão nas respostas... Basta ver o histórico de edições da pergunta que deve bater alguns recordes :D (_mas obrigado pelo Feedback_).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Não é necessário incluir a barra no final do elemento, [embora isso seja permitido no caso dos elementos nulos](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#start-tags), para alegria dos fanáticos por XML:

> [*Sobre a sintaxe das tags de abertura*]
>
> 6. Then, if the element is one of the void elements, or if the element is a foreign element, then there may be a single "/" (U+002F) character. This character has no effect on void elements, but on foreign elements it marks the start tag as self-closing.

Tradução livre:

> Se o elemento for um dos elementos nulos, ou se for um elemento estrangeiro, então um único caracter "/" (U+002F) pode ser incluído. Esse caractere não tem efeito em elementos nulos, mas em elementos estrangeiros marca a tag de abertura como auto-fechada.

Portanto em HTML5 ambas as opções abaixo são [válidas](http://validator.w3.org/)* para a tag `meta`:

```html
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
```

<sup>(Eu pessoalmente acho a primeira opção preferível, por ser mais limpa.)</sup>

O [texto da especificação](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#void-elements) que você citou diz:

> Void elements only have a start tag; end tags must not be specified for void elements

Ou seja:

> Elementos nulos têm somente uma tag de abertura; tags de fechamento não devem ser utilizadas em elementos nulos.

Isso significa que uma tag de fechamento `</meta>` é inválida, não que `<meta />` seja inválido.

Em XML, ou XHTML, quando você escreve algo como `<img />`, isso equivale a `<img></img>`. A barra no final é apenas um atalho para indicar ao *parser* que a tag está sendo fechada, sem conteúdo, já que em XML todas as tags devem obrigatoriamente ser fechadas. HTML5 não é XML, e não funciona da mesma maneira.

---

<sup>* O validador do W3C diz que o suporte a HTML5 é experimental, mas acredito que para este caso o resultado seja confiável</sup>

Comment: Existe algum "validador" oficial de HTML5, que cheque um código fonte? Acho que você poderia colocar em sua resposta, pra complementar :)

Comment: @CalebeOliveira Existe o super oficial [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) mas a componente de HTML5 ainda está em fase experimental!

Answer (score 3):

Vou acrescentar alguns pontos que considero importantes a respeito do assunto.

## Elementos não nulos NÃO podem ser fechados com `/>`

[Este artigo](http://tiffanybbrown.com/2011/03/23/html5-does-not-allow-self-closing-tags/) é muito esclarecedor sobre o assunto. Por exemplo, se você enviar para o [validador do W3C](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://tiffanybbrown.com/not-all-html5-tags-are-self-closing/index.html&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) algo como `<a id="selfclosinganchor" />`, receberá o seguinte erro de validação:

> Self-closing syntax (/>) used on a non-void HTML element. Ignoring the slash and treating as a start tag.

Que significa:

> Sintaxe de auto-fechamento (/>) usada em um elemento HTML não-nulo. Ignorando a barra e tratando como um elemento de abertura.

E como não haverá um elemento de fechamento, poderão ocorrer mais erros no HTML.

## Existem vantagens em usar auto-fechamento em tags nulas

- Compatibilidade com interpretadores e navegadores antigos de HTML
- Compatibilidade com interpretadores de XML
- *Pode-se* evitar problemas em alguns interpretadores, principalmente os "caseiros" que nem sempre levam em consideração a especificação

## Tags não nulas e não fechadas podem causar problemas

Embora alguns interpretadores de HTML sejam "inteligentes" a ponto de ignorar tags não fechadas (algumas pessoas fazem isso para evitar digitação ou para [economizar alguns bytes](http://enterprise-html.com/16)), isso pode sim levar a [erros](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/798866/many-unclosed-tags-cause-stack-overflow) e [impactar no desempenho](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72885) da renderização da página.

Não consegui achar a fonte de um texto que li há alguns anos sobre como o *parser* do Internet Explorer encarava tags não fechadas, mas basicamente ele ia empilhando as tags abertas até finalizar a leitura de todo o documento e então aplicava um algoritmo de ajuste. Isso significa que quando há tags não fechadas o tempo de renderização seria o pior possível, pois ele não iria mostrar o conteúdo até ler o `</html>` e aplicar o tal algoritmo, que causada um *delay* visível.

Comment: *Elementos não nulos NÃO podem ser fechados com `/>`* – exceto os [estrangeiros](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#foreign-elements)